# Need help overcoming this error in Ionic v3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Everytime i try to delcare my provider into the .ts file's constructor i get the following error when running my app.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhy7H.jpg

here is my TS File and the corresponding html file with the provider's ts file too.
It seems to be okay after just importing the provider into the ts File but whenever i enter in the provider into the constructor i get that error. Something about the HTTP Client, but I dont remember ever creating a provider for HTTP Client in class so I'm unsure how to proceed.

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { CurrencyRatesProvider } from '../../providers/currency-rates/currency-rates';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-converter',
  templateUrl: 'converter.html',
})

export class ConverterPage {
changingFrom:string;
changingTo:String;
conversion:number=0;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage, private currencyRatesProvider: CurrencyRatesProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
   console.log('ionViewDidLoad ConverterPage');

    }


  onSave(){
console.log(this.changingFrom+" "+this.changingTo);

this.storage.set("changingFrom",this.changingFrom);
this.storage.set("changingTo",this.changingTo);


  }
     ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.storage.get("changingFrom").then((data) => {
      this.changingFrom=data;
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error = " + err);
    })


    this.storage.get("changingTo").then((data) => {
      this.changingTo=data;
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error = " + err);
    })

}


 }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title text-center>Converter</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>

      <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Enter amount" floating>    </ion-input>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="changingFrom">
        <ion-option value="euro">Euro</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>


   <ion-list>

     <ion-item>

       <ion-select right [(ngModel)]="changingTo">
    <ion-option value="euro">Euro</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="usd">USDollars</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="aud">Austrailian Dollars</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="cad">Canadian Dollars</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="sek">Swedish Krona</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="mxn">Mexican Peso</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
   </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
        <h2> Your amount is {{conversion}}</h2>
      <button ion-button large color="secondary"  (onclick)="onSave()">Convert</button>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

 </ion-content>
```

**provider ts**

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CurrencyRatesProvider {

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
console.log('Hello CurrencyRatesProvider Provider');
}

  GetMovieData():Observable<any>{
return this.http.get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=2d41e1b777f6f0002852f4e1608af906&symbols=USD,AUD,CAD,PLN,MXN&format=1")

   } 

 }
```

Comment: Have you added HttpClientModule in the imports of your NgModule? https://angular.io/guide/http#setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JBNizet said, In your module.ts file (Mostly app.module.ts) add HttpClientModule

```
...    
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
      ...
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```